# Integrate Git commit history into my site

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I have to integrate GIT commit history with links into my site like if user click on that link automatically go to that commit on stash.
So i don,t have any idea about , If you have any idea about any API or any helping link for me please share.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use bitbucket API. here are the documentation.
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit

or if you use github you can read this one .
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/